# extract data out of a windows application with python

Tags: python, windows, dictionary, automation, scrape

So I have been doing some web scraping with python. I now want to scrape data out of a very old dictionary software on windows. I want to be able to extract meaning of words and save it in a .csv

I have read all similar questions but they are about web scraping and not screen scraping the windows applications.

It also would be nice to be able to automate the searching of words and getting the result back. I am not sure about any other windows automation python library other than pyautogui.

thanks in advance

Comment: We need to know a few things in order to help. What dictionary software? What format does it use to save and show data? Does it have a database we can crawl?

Comment: There is no generic solution for such a problem. If you are lucky, maybe you can find a file where it keeps the data. If you are less lucky, you may have to access the applications's widgets using Windows API and hope that you can extract the data that way. Or you may be able to find some software which can be automatized to click around in the application and collect the data it finds into a file.

Comment: I think this might be too broad and vague.